# Avoid adding new UFW after docker restart

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, docker, ufw

I'm hosting a web application on my server and want to it to be reachable only from a few specific IPs. UFW/iptables sounds like a good choice here.

After reading [The dangers of UFW + Docker](https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2014/11/03/the-dangers-of-ufw-docker.html) I've decided to add `--iptables=false` in my `DOCKER_OPTS`. I've a deny incoming default policy, so I had to add some ufw rules.

First these two:

```
172.17.0.0/16 on docker0   ALLOW IN    172.17.0.0/16
172.18.0.0/16 on docker0   ALLOW IN    172.18.0.0/16
```

But also on an interface that looks like this `br-*******`. The thing is that this interface changes every time I restart my containers forcing me to add a new ufw rule. So far it looks like this.

```
PUBLIC_IP on br-e16af56aa604 ALLOW IN    172.19.0.0/16
PUBLIC_IP on br-f0b860d26add ALLOW IN    172.20.0.0/16
PUBLIC_IP on br-c0cdd3a4d7a6 ALLOW IN    172.20.0.0/16
PUBLIC_IP on br-c0cdd3a4d7a6 ALLOW IN    172.21.0.0/16
```

At each restart I have to look at my `ifconfig` and do a `sudo ufw allow in on br-*** from br-***-INTERFACE-IP to PUBLIC_IP`.

Is there a to add a persistent rule to fix my issue ? Thanks

Comment: Viktor's ramblings here are kind of misleading. The behavior he describes is what most people expect to happen. If you don't want Docker allowing ports in the firewall that you've explicitly asked to be opened to the public, then you're a very rare person indeed! And ufw is not "complicated" enough to reproduce the firewall rules Docker needs for internal communication, so you would have to do something manually, which is where you are now. I suggest ignoring him and going back to allowing Docker to do its thing.

Comment: The thing is I'm serving a web app, but I just want it to be reachable on a few specific IPs :)

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host